# How to prevent splitting of anchor tag text across two lines while resizing?

Tags: html, css

I have an anchor tag where I display the name of the person logged in. The problem is that when I resize the browser window, the name gets split across two lines. How to prevent it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this JSFiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/rickydam/4xbztwbb/2/

---

HTML

```
<a href="https://rickydam.com" class="dontwrap"> Ricky Dam </a>
```

CSS

```
.dontwrap {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```